# Unable to save settings with QSettings

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a very simple test project under Windows 7 with the following code only on the main window:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QSettings>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::IniFormat);
    QSettings settings("./conf.ini");

    settings.setValue("testconf", 123);

    settings.sync();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I just made a project from scratch and the MainWindow is empty. For reference, I add the .pro content, though it should not be relevant:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = qsettingstest
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I tried different paths for the settings file, using `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation)`, existing directories e.g. "c:\mydir". I tried also replacing `QSettings settings("./conf.ini");` with `QSettings *psettings = new QSettings("./conf.ini");`, call `sync` or not call it, but:

The file is not created or modified (in case I create it manually before). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use 1 QString constructor for `QSettings`. This will set the *Organization Name*, not the file name (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings, application name is defaulted to an empty QString).
This will store/read the settings from the windows registry. Check for a ./conf.ini key there

You want to use the `QSetting` constructor taking a filename and a format (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings-3):

```
QSettings settings("./conf.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
```